# struts2-jquery-plugin : radio-buttons have got the form of buttons

Tags: struts2-jquery

I use struts2-jquery-plugin to implement my form. But as a result, my radio button get the form of a button, and not a radio ( check this link : http://struts.jgeppert.com/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action) ... I wonder if there is a way to give them the natural look. Thank you a lot.

```
<s:url id="remoteurl" action="jsonsample"/> 
<sj:radio
href="%{remoteurl}" 
id="remoteRadiobuttons" 
name="echo" 
list="languageMap" 
label="Language"
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching a solution for another issue, I accidently found this :

```
buttonset="false"
```

and it resolved my problem. I hope it helps somebody else.